# Include Swiftmailer Library in Kohana

Tags: php, include, kohana, swiftmailer

I am having trouble finding the right way to include the swiftmailer library in my Kohana app.  I am using the recommended:

```
require_once Kohana::find_file('vendor','swift/lib/swift_required');
```

but this is the error I get back:

```
Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php')
```

Why would Kohana be returning the path to php library instead of looking in the folder I passed to `find_file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out and Ill post the answer for any other Kohana noobs like myself.  `find_file` is looking in the `application` directory.  Do not use the vendor directory that comes with Kohana, create a new one inside the application and it will find it.